# Django Improved UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-views

I have this UpDateView class and I need just author of article can edit the blog .I had the solution for the CreateView class(using def Form_valid) but it doesn't work for UpdateView class :::

```
class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = models.Article
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'
    fields = ['title','body']
    login_url = 'login'

class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = models.Article
    template_name = 'article_new.html'
    fields = ['title','body',]
    login_url='login'


    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Why not? What happens when you add the form_valid into the update class?

Comment: Actually It made me surprised because logically  it should works. I created 3 users but every users can edit and delete other users post. I copied and pasted Form_valid  for other views but it just works for CreateView....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method in your view class:

```
class ArticleUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = models.Article
    template_name = 'article_edit.html'
    fields = ['title','body']
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article = super().get_object(*args, **kwargs)

        if article.author != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied('You should be the author of this article.')

        return article
```

Comment: it worked Thank  so much Man. . I need to dig into your solution more  Again  I'm thankful

Comment: @DaniMHM I'm glad that I've helped. Make sure to accept the solution in order to guide future viewers of your question.